# Immediate attribute - varying behaviors

Tags: apex, visualforce

Page

```
<apex:page controller="ActionFunctionController">
<apex:form>
<apex:actionFunction name="getName" action="{!findName}" rerender="acctphone" />
<apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs1">
            <apex:inputfield id="acctphone" value="{!acct.phone}" required="true" />
            <!--  apex:outputlabel value="click" styleclass="btn" onclick="getName()"  / -->

            <apex:inputCheckbox                 id="PhoneCheckBox"
                                                value="{!checkPhone}"
                                                onchange="getName()" 
                                                immediate="true" />

            <!-- apex:commandlink value="click" action="{!click}" immediate="true" rerender="acctphone" / -->
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
 public with sharing class ActionFunctionController {
    public Account acct{get;set;}
    public boolean checkPhone{get;set;}

    public ActionFunctionController(){
        acct = new Account();
    }

    public void findName(){
        acct.phone = '1234567890xx';
    }
    public void click(){
        acct.phone = '1234567890xx';
    }
}
```

Question. When I remove the "required" attribute from inputfield, it works fine. However, despite having the "Immediate" attribute on the inputCheckBox, it's not bypassing the required field validations. However, if I use a commandlink or commandbutton (commented line), the immediate attribute works just fine. Is this a "salesforce bug" that's been reported or is there anything that I'm missing.

I'm testing out the ActionFunction where when I click a checkbox, I'm trying to populate a phone #. That's the end objective of this exercise.

Comment: i'm kind of surprised `immediate` is an allowed attribute on inputCheckbox as it isn't on `inputText`. `Immediate` typically appears as an attribute on VF components that do some POST action like `commandLink`, 'actionFunction`, or `commandButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `immediate` attribute to the `action function`. because from your action function you are calling the controller method. Try this it will solve your problem.

Comment: Tushar, This is working but I'm not able to pass the value of the field into the controller. I thought immediate bypasses only validation rules but it also bypasses any user selections too...any thoughts.